# Can't build TCP connection with peers to send handshake message in golang, Bittorrent client

Tags: go, tcp, p2p, bittorrent

I am trying to build a bittorrent client. I wrote this function to verify that I can establish connection to send messages to other peers but its not working.

```
func handShake(torrent *gotorrentparser.Torrent, peer Peer, peedId []byte) {

    conn,err := net.Dial("tcp", peer.ip + ":" + strconv.Itoa(int(peer.port)))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
}
```

Here peer is a struct of string ip and uint16 port.

Getting the following error:
panic: dial tcp 152.57.73.47:27569: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Couldn't find any similar issues. I tried to fix my local port address to be same as what I used to send the announce request but that didn't work either.

Edit: I tried with a different torrent, it is failing for some peers, but now it is working for some other peers. Is the issue only when the peer is using utorrent as bittorrent clients?

Comment: You got the IP wrong, you got the port wrong, there's no network route from 'here to there' and/or 'there to here', or the server isn't running.

Comment: How could it be wrong if I received it from the tracker?

Comment: At this point I'd suggest using wireshark to find out what's really going on in the network.

Comment: Either connection blocked with firewall or use 127.0.0.1 or any local address insted of IP. because there is nothing wrong with code.

Comment: "How could it be wrong if I received it from the tracker?"  Trackers are often wrong

Comment: @MandeepGill How can I rectify that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing a bittorrent client you should start with a more reproducable setup such as running an existing client with a known infohash on your local machine and then connecting to that (without using a tracker). Once you got that to work you can work on a tracker client implementation and then put those pieces together.

The internet is unreliable and bittorrent consists of many moving parts, so a single connection failure won't tell you much, you'll have to ensure that each part works properly and try with torrents that you have tested in an existing client to narrow down the cause of problems.

Comment: I did exacly the same. I hosted a torrent from u torrent and the I tried to connect to it. But can't connect for handshake

Answer (score 0):

After few days here is the problem that I found.

- Not all peers are able to accept an inbound request as they are behind a NAT.

Even when I hosted a torrent from one of my computer and tried to download through another system, I couldn't download as there was no reply from the peer for the SYN message being sent.
I was only able to download, when both the clients were on the same network and local peer discovery was enabled, and the TCP connection was also build with the local IP address.